# Cross-browser HTML5 audio player

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I am using `audio` tag to play a `wav` audio, My url is genereted by `URL.createObjectURL()` and the url is like `blob:http://localhost/9fa2ef06-ade6-4027-89f8-06cd2c176405`

As the url has no extension, I have some issue with safari

The following code is works on chrome and not works on safari(Audio player is disabled)

```html
<audio src="MY_BLOB_URL" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

The following code is works on safari and not works on chrome

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="MY_BLOB_URL" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

I tried weird codes like the following and cannot find any way to works on both browsers

```html
<audio src="MY_BLOB_URL" type="audio/wav">
  <source src="MY_BLOB_URL" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

What's wrong here? And how can I have a cross-browser HTML5 audio player with single code?

Comment: Where is the Javascript? The Safari working code (2nd example) is the setup I use to play audio in Chrome, but I use JS to update the `<source>` tag's **.src**. Do you have a JS function that does the `URL.createObjectURL()`? If yes, why not update the `<source>` via same function?

Comment: I have is codes , for simplistically I use MY_BLOB_URL placeholder as the result of `URL.createObjectURL` in the question

Comment: The fastest example I can think of to get a blob is via file-browse, I'll write such example code and then you can test if it may be useful. I am on Windows PC so cannot test Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the following code on Windows PC using Chrome, Edge & Firefox.
Let's hope it also works on Safari.

PS: For future readers, this code would also work with an MP3 blob (set as `accept=".mp3"`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head> <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"> </head>

<body>

<div style="z-index: 1; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 50px">
<audio id="tag_Audio1" controls>
<source type="audio/wav">
</audio>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div style="z-index: 1; overflow:hidden; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 50px">
<p> Choose an WAV file...</p>
<input type="file" id="choose_media" accept=".wav" />
</div>

<script>

var file; var reader;
var tmpElement; //# is reference to aTag for holding image content.
var file_Blob; //# is reference to file BLOB (data of selected file).

const  myAudio = document.getElementById("tag_Audio1");
document.getElementById("choose_media").addEventListener("change", onFile_Selected, false);

function onFile_Selected(evt) 
{
    file = evt.target.files[0]; //# access to selected file
    
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); //# load selected file as Blob
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", onFile_Loaded, false);
}

function onFile_Loaded(evt) 
{
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
    {
        //# remove any current SRC
        myAudio.removeAttribute("src");
        
        //# create blob
        file_Blob = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
        
        //# apply blob & test play
        myAudio.setAttribute("src", file_Blob);
        myAudio.load();
        myAudio.play();
    }   
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```